# How to print the duplicates value while converting from Dictionary to List in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, collections

I am trying to converting from dictionary to list while converting I am getting the output

I/p-

```
          dic.Add("Demo1",2);
          dic.Add("Demo2",1);
          dic.Add("Demo3",1);
            
          dic.Add("Demo4",2);
```

O/p-
Demo1
Demo2
Demo3
Demo4

But I need Demo1 and Demo4 two times because their quantity are 2. So How can I achieve that??

Below is the code

```
 public IList<string> DictionaryToList(IDictionary<string,int> dictionary)

        {
            
            IDictionary<string, int> dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            IList<string> lst = new List<string>();
            
            dic.Add("Demo1",2);
            dic.Add("Demo2",1);
            dic.Add("Demo3",1);
            
            dic.Add("Demo4",2); 

           
            foreach (var item in dic)
            {
                if (!lst.Contains(item.Key))
                {

                    lst.Add(item.Key);
                   
                   
                }

                
            }
            
            return lst;

        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var conversion = new Conversion();
            var list = new List<string> { "Demo1","Demo2","Demo3","Demo4","Demo1","Demo4"};
            var dictionary = conversion.ListToDictionary(list);
            foreach (var item in dictionary)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key}, {item.Value}");
            }
            var convertedList = conversion.DictionaryToList(dictionary);
            foreach (var item in convertedList)

            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item}");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ's `SelectMany` and `Enumerable.Repeat`:

```
IList<string> list = dictionary
    .SelectMany(kv => Enumerable.Repeat(kv.Key, kv.Value))
    .ToList();
```

Here is also the opposite way to build your dictionary from the list:

```
var list = new List<string> { "Demo1", "Demo2", "Demo3", "Demo4", "Demo1", "Demo4" };
var dictionary = list.GroupBy(s => s).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

IList<string> list2 = dictionary
    .SelectMany(kv => Enumerable.Repeat(kv.Key, kv.Value))
    .ToList();
```

So at the end `list2` contains the same strings as `list` but in a different order.

Answer (score 2):

Your dictionary consists of a key (`string`) and a value (`int`). After checking

`if (!list.Contains(item.Key))` just add another loop which goes from 0 to the actual value from your dictionary-item and adds the new item `n`-times.

```
for (int i = 0; i < item.Value; i++) // Demo1 and Demo4 runs 2x, Demo2 and Demo3 1x
    lst.Add(item.Key);
```

Comment: I always like plain and basic programming because it always encourages your programmatic thinking. But you could also do it with LINQ like being said by Tim Schmelter in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
        Dictionary<string, int> dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        List<string> lst = new List<string>();

        dic.Add("Demo1", 2);
        dic.Add("Demo2", 1);
        dic.Add("Demo3", 1);
        dic.Add("Demo4", 2);

        foreach (var item in dic)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < item.Value; i++)
            {
                lst.Add(item.Key);
            }
        }
```